# Setting a property to different values depending on user input

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have two colors:

```
CGColorRef purpleColor = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(0.604, 0.247, 0.463, 1.0);
CGColorRef blackColor = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

And a CALayer:

```
    NSView *contentView = [window contentView];
    [contentView setWantsLayer:YES];
    CALayer *layer = [contentView layer];
    layer.backgroundColor = colorVariable;
    layer.opacity = 0;
    [window makeFirstResponder:contentView];
```

I want to be able to set `layer.backgroundColor` to be a CGColorRef Variable and then be able to change it between different colors in an IBAction

```
- (IBAction)setColor:(id)sender
{
   //Change Color Variable
}
```

How can I do this? thanks!

Comment: Can't you just add the code that you already have to setColor?  What is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: You already set the colour before: layer.backgroundColor = purpleColor; What is the problem?

Comment: updated question, I want to use a button to switch between the two colors, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the action, read the state of the button (if it's a checkbox) or identify it (if you have two buttons). Depending on the state you get back/which button was clicked, set the layer's color to one color or the other.

Alternatively, you might consider replacing the button(s) with an NSColorWell.